# Send recorded audio to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client, recorder.js

I am using [RecorderJs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) to record audio. When done; I want to save it to amazon S3 (I am using knox library) via server (because I don't want to share the key).

```
recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
    // sending it to server 
});
```

On the server side, using knox ...

```
knox.putBuffer(blob, path, {"Content-Type": 'audio/wav', 
                            "Content-Length": blob.length},
                           function(e,r) {
                               if (!e) {
                                   console.log("saved at " + path);
                                   future.return(path);
                               } else {
                                   console.log(e);
                               }
                           });
```

And this is saving just 2 bytes!!

Also; is this the best way to save server memory. Or are there better alternatives?

I also see this: `Recorder.forceDownload(blob[, filename])`

Should I force download and then send it to server?

Or should I save to S3 directly from my domain. Is there a option in S3 which cannot be hacked by other user trying to store data on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or should i save to S3 directly from my domain. Is there a option in
>   S3 which cannot be hacked by other user trying to store data on my
>   server?

You can use S3 bucket policies or AIM policies on S3 buckets to restrict access to your buckets.

Bucket Policies:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html

AIM Policies: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingIAMPolicies.html

There are several related threads on SO about this too, for example:

[Enabling AWS IAM Users access to shared bucket/objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960487/enabling-aws-iam-users-access-to-shared-bucket-objects)

[AWS s3 bucket policy invalid group principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063868/aws-s3-bucket-policy-invalid-group-principal)